# Android: Binding Layout with Dynamic Sublayout (ViewHolder & SubViewHolder)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I am parsing JSON from server to Android and storing data in SQLite in which i have two tables `news` and `news_attachment`.

I have done code for displaying `news` and `news_attachment` in list but now i want to display multiple attachment for one news.

> The following code displaying last_attachment of the particular news.
>   I want to display all attachment with Custom Layout which will be settle automatically in parent view.

#### NewsAdapter.java

```
public class NewsAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    DatabaseHelper dbHelper;

    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public NewsAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
        String[] from, int[] to, int flags) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to, flags);

    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    dbHelper.open();
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View convertView, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    if(cursor.isNull(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.NEWS_TITLE))) {
        holder.newsTitleText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        holder.newsTitleText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.newsTitleText.setText(""+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.NEWS_TITLE)));
    }

    if(cursor.isNull(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.NEWS_TEXT))) {
        holder.newsText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        holder.newsText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        String newsText = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.NEWS_TEXT));
        newsText = Html.fromHtml(newsText).toString();
        holder.newsText.setText(newsText);
    }

    /***************************
     *  Getting Child Cursor... 
     */
    Cursor newsAttachmentCursor;
    int newsId;

    /**
     * Setting up values of news_Attachment Table...
     */
    newsId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.NEWS_SERVER_ID));
    newsAttachmentCursor = dbHelper.getNewsAttachment(newsId);

    /**
     * Displaying news Attachment
     */
    if(newsAttachmentCursor.getCount() > 0 && newsAttachmentCursor != null){
        newsAttachmentCursor.moveToFirst();

        /**
         * Displaying NEWS_AT_NAME
         */
        if(newsAttachmentCursor.isNull(newsAttachmentCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.NEWS_AT_NAME))) {
        holder.newsAttachment.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else{
        holder.newsAttachment.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        /**
         * Displaying If attachment has Images....
         */
        String fileName = newsAttachmentCursor.getString(newsAttachmentCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.NEWS_AT_NAME));
        String fileUrl = newsAttachmentCursor.getString(newsAttachmentCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.NEWS_AT_URL));

        String tempLowerUrl = fileUrl.toLowerCase();
        if(tempLowerUrl != null && (tempLowerUrl.contains("png") || tempLowerUrl.contains("jpeg") || tempLowerUrl.contains("jpg") || tempLowerUrl.contains("ttif") || tempLowerUrl.contains("gif")))
        {
            holder.newsAttachment.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.newsImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Log.d("oopscv2", "File : "+fileUrl);
            new AQuery(mContext).id(holder.newsImage).image(newsAttachmentCursor.getString(newsAttachmentCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.NEWS_AT_URL)), true, true, 0, R.drawable.no_image, null, AQuery.FADE_IN);
        } else {
            holder.newsAttachment.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.newsImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.newsAttachment.setText(fileName);    
        }
        }
    } else {
        holder.newsAttachment.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.newsImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_news_row, parent, false);
    v.setTag(new ViewHolder(v));
    return v;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder
    {
    TextView newsTitleText;
    TextView newsText;
    ImageView newsImage;
    TextView newsAttachment;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        newsTitleText   = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.newsTitleText);
        newsText        = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.newsText);
        newsImage       = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.newsImage);
        newsAttachment  = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.newsAttachment);
    }
    }
}
```

Current Output:

[image: Output]

#### I want dynamic output like (temporary 4 attachment):

[image]

**I think dynamic view is useful for this but i dont know how to add dynamically view with formatting with *onClick listener* for all attachment.**

Hows its possible.?

---

### Updated Question after solved above question:

Now i have following Updated Adapter:

#### NewsNewAdapter.java

```
public class NewsAdapterNew extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    DatabaseHelper dbHelper;

    LayoutInflater inflater;

    ViewHolder holder;

    ViewHolder.SubViewHolder subHolder;

    String DIRPATH = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "TEMP" + File.separator;

    public NewsAdapterNew(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
        String[] from, int[] to, int flags) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to, flags);

    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    dbHelper.open();
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View convertView, final Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    if(cursor.isNull(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.NEWS_TITLE))) {
        holder.newsTitleText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        holder.newsTitleText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.newsTitleText.setText(""+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.NEWS_TITLE)));
    }

    if(cursor.isNull(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.NEWS_TEXT))) {
        holder.newsText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        holder.newsText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        String newsText = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.NEWS_TEXT));
        newsText = Html.fromHtml(newsText).toString();
        holder.newsText.setText(newsText);
    }

    /***************************
     *  Getting Child Cursor... 
     */
    Cursor newsAttachmentCursor;
    int newsId;

    /**
     * Setting up values of news_Attachment Table...
     */
    newsId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.NEWS_SERVER_ID));
    newsAttachmentCursor = dbHelper.getNewsAttachment(newsId);

    Log.d(TAG, "newsAttachmentCursor.getCount() : " +newsAttachmentCursor.getCount());

    /**
     * Displaying news Attachment
     */
    if(newsAttachmentCursor.getCount() > 0 && newsAttachmentCursor != null){
        //newsAttachmentCursor.moveToFirst();

        /**
         * Displaying NEWS_AT_NAME
         */
        holder.layoutAttachment.removeAllViews();

        newsAttachmentCursor.moveToFirst();

        do {

        View viewAttachement = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.attachment_layout, null);

        subHolder = new com.salesman.adapter.NewsAdapterNew.ViewHolder.SubViewHolder(viewAttachement);

        subHolder.newsImage.setTag(subHolder);
        subHolder.newsImageDownload.setTag(subHolder);
        subHolder.newsAttachmentFileName.setTag(subHolder);

        /**
         * Displaying If attachment has Images....
         */
        subHolder.fileName = newsAttachmentCursor.getString(newsAttachmentCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.NEWS_AT_NAME));
        subHolder.fileUrl = newsAttachmentCursor.isNull(newsAttachmentCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.NEWS_AT_URL)) ? "" :  newsAttachmentCursor.getString(newsAttachmentCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.NEWS_AT_URL));

        subHolder.newsAttachmentFileName.setText(subHolder.fileName);

        String tempExt = subHolder.fileUrl.contains(".") ? subHolder.fileUrl.substring(subHolder.fileUrl.lastIndexOf(".")).toLowerCase() : "";

        Log.d(TAG, "Temp Extension : "+tempExt);

        if(!tempExt.isEmpty()) {

            File myFile = new File(DIRPATH + subHolder.fileName);

            if(myFile.exists()) {
            subHolder.newsImageDownload.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
            subHolder.newsImageDownload.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            if(tempExt != null && tempExt.equals(".mp4") || (tempExt.equals(".jpeg") || tempExt.equals(".jpg") || tempExt.equals(".ttif") || tempExt.equals(".gif") || tempExt.equals(".png")|| tempExt.equals(".pdf")|| tempExt.equals(".docx")|| tempExt.equals(".doc")|| tempExt.equals(".xls")|| tempExt.equals(".xlsx")|| tempExt.equals(".ppt")|| tempExt.equals(".pptx")|| tempExt.equals(".txt")|| tempExt.equals(".zip")))
            {
            subHolder.newsImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            if(tempExt.equals(".pdf")) {
                new AQuery(mContext).id(subHolder.newsImage).image(R.drawable.ic_pdf);
            } else if(tempExt.equals(".doc") || tempExt.equals(".docx")) {
                new AQuery(mContext).id(subHolder.newsImage).image(R.drawable.ic_word);
            } else if(tempExt.equals(".xls") || tempExt.equals(".xlsx")) {
                new AQuery(mContext).id(subHolder.newsImage).image(R.drawable.ic_excel);
            } else if(tempExt.equals(".ppt") || tempExt.equals(".pptx")) {
                new AQuery(mContext).id(subHolder.newsImage).image(R.drawable.ic_ppt);
            } else if(tempExt.equals(".txt")) {
                new AQuery(mContext).id(subHolder.newsImage).image(R.drawable.ic_text);
            } else if(tempExt.equals(".zip")) {
                new AQuery(mContext).id(subHolder.newsImage).image(R.drawable.ic_zip);
            } else if(tempExt.equals(".mp4")) {
                new AQuery(mContext).id(subHolder.newsImage).image(R.drawable.ic_video);
            } else {
                subHolder.newsImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                new AQuery(mContext).id(subHolder.newsImage).image(subHolder.fileUrl, true, true, 0, R.drawable.no_image, null, AQuery.FADE_IN);
            }
            } else {
            subHolder.newsImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            subHolder.newsImageDownload.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            /***
             * 
             */
            subHolder.newsImageDownload.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                com.salesman.adapter.NewsAdapterNew.ViewHolder.SubViewHolder tempHolder = ((com.salesman.adapter.NewsAdapterNew.ViewHolder.SubViewHolder)v.getTag());
                //Toast.makeText(mContext, tempHolder.fileName.toString() + " is Downloading...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                if(InternetConnection.checkConnection(context)) {
                tempHolder.newsImageDownload.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                tempHolder.pBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                new DownloadFileAsync().execute(tempHolder);
                } else {
                tempHolder.newsImageDownload.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                tempHolder.pBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                AlertDialogManager.showAlertDialog(context, "Download failed", "The download was unable to complete. Please try again later.", false);
                }
            }
            });


            subHolder.newsImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                com.salesman.adapter.NewsAdapterNew.ViewHolder.SubViewHolder tempHolder = ((com.salesman.adapter.NewsAdapterNew.ViewHolder.SubViewHolder)v.getTag());

                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Downloaded : " + tempHolder.fileName.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                File myFile = new File(DIRPATH + tempHolder.fileName.toString());

                FileOpen.openFile(mContext, myFile);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.d(TAG, "Error While Opening : "+e.getLocalizedMessage());
                }
            }
            });

                /** Adding News Attachment Layout in Parent LinearLayout **/
            holder.layoutAttachment.addView(viewAttachement);
        }

        viewAttachement.setTag(subHolder);

        } while(newsAttachmentCursor.moveToNext());

    } else {
        holder.layoutAttachment.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_news_row, parent, false);
    v.setTag(new ViewHolder(v));
    return v;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder
    {
    TextView newsTitleText;
    TextView newsText;
    LinearLayout layoutAttachment;

    static class SubViewHolder {
        ImageView newsImage,newsImageDownload;
        TextView newsAttachmentFileName;
        ProgressBar pBar;

        String fileUrl;
        String fileName;

        public SubViewHolder(View subView) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        newsImage   = (ImageView) subView.findViewById(R.id.newsImage);
        newsImageDownload =(ImageView) subView.findViewById(R.id.newsImageDownload);
        pBar        = (ProgressBar) subView.findViewById(R.id.newsProgressBar);
        newsAttachmentFileName = (TextView) subView.findViewById(R.id.newsAttachment);
        }
    }

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        newsTitleText   = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.newsTitleText);
        newsText        = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.newsText);
        layoutAttachment = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.linear_news_row_attachment);
    }
    }
}
```

#### frag_new_row.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/newsLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_white_shadow"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/newsTitleText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:text="News From"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/common_title_textview"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/newsText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="News Text News Text"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/common_fontsize" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_news_row_attachment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

### Problem:

> While scrolling sometimes all News Attachment per News going to blank. I think this problem occurring in adapter while binding view but i cant found.

You will more understand this by following images.

### Output Before Scrolling:

[image: Before Scrolling]

#### Output After Scrolling:

[image: After Scrolling]

**Is my adapter code is wrong? What mistake i have done in Adapter?**

Your help would be appreciated.

Thanks & Regards,

Pratik

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve your goal is to add view for each attachment programmatically.
You must do smth like this:
make holder.newsAttachments - linearLayout, for example.

Then in your bindView method:

```
holder.newsAttachment.removeAllViews(); //remove views if it exists
while (newsAttachmentCursor.moveToNext()) {
  View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_for_attachment, null);

  //fill view
  String fileName = newsAttachmentCursor.getString(newsAttachmentCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.NEWS_AT_NAME));
  view.setTag(fileName); // add as tag something, what you need inside onCLickListener
  ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.attachment_view_name)).setText(fullName);
  holder.newsAttachment.addView(view);
  view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    void onClick(View v) {
       String fileName = (String) v.getTag();
       //do what you want with file name, or anything what you've added to tag.
    }
  });
}
```

It's only example, but this idea will works fine for small amount of attachments.

Comment: `holder.newAttachment` is TextView, so is it possible to addView in TextView or i have to take another Parent Layout.

Comment: how to get click listener of object who created on view

Comment: @PratikButani Yes, you must add paren layout. For example you can make LinearLayout(with horizontal orientation). And you don't need to have your textView for attachments in Layout, because you will create it dinamically.

Comment: @APOORVADOSHI To add click listener to created view, you can call view.setOnClickListener(onClickListener).

Comment: @Demand Thank you demand but how can i set click listener on all attachment?

Comment: @APOORVADOSHI I updated my answer with onClick Listener. Pls note, I'm writing code right here and it may have some stupid mistakes.

Comment: @PratikButani no, it's not null. I set it above with view.setTag(fileName); // add as tag something, what you need inside onCLickListener

Comment: @Demand if there are two images in (layout_for_attachment) layout
i want to fire click event in both then it's work
but when on click one image i want to visibility gone then without re call view not working

Comment: @APOORVADOSHI I don't completely understand what you mean. Please post new question with your code and what not working. I will try to help you.

Comment: please post it as separate question. And provide full code of your adapter.

Comment: @Demand I have updated my Question, I got that problem while binding view of Attachment